# Show that $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{g(a+h)-2g(a)+g(a-h)}{h^2} = g''(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $C^2$. Show that
$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{g(a+h)-2g(a)+g(a-h)}{h^2} = g''(a)$$

we cannot pass the limit inside. How to proceed with the problem?

Comment: L'hopital's Rule perhaps?

Comment: The question only needs the existence of $g''(a) $ and nothing more. The result is proved easily proved by a single application of L'Hospital's Rule.

Answer (score 5):

Correct me if wrong.

Mean value theorem, $g \in C^2 $;

1)$ \dfrac {g(a+h) - g(a)}{h} = g'(r) $

where $r \in (a,a+h).$

2)$ \dfrac{g(a-h) - g(a)}{h} = g'(s)$

where $s \in (a-h,a).$

3) $\dfrac{g'(r) - g'(s)}{h} = g''(t)$

where $t \in (s,r)$.

$g''(x)$ is continuous, and $t \in (a-h,a+h)$.

We have :

$h \rightarrow 0$ and $t \in  (a-h,a+h)$

$\Rightarrow t \rightarrow a$:

Finally:

4) $\lim_{t \rightarrow a} g''(t) = g''(a)$.

Comment: +1 Great answer.  Of course if you trace back you probably find that MVT is used in the proofs of those things like l'Hôpital and Taylor in the other proofs.

Comment: Edgar. Thanks, Peter. g \in C^2 only. Need C^3  for continuity of g"?

Comment: Definition of $C^2$ says $g''$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks, Edgar, was not sure anymore.

Comment: at 3) we should have $\dfrac{g'(r)-g'(s)}{r-s} = g''(t)$

Comment: Tiago.3) seems ok now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

How about using Taylor's formula:
$$\begin{align}g(a+h)&=g(a)+hg'(a)+\frac{h^2}{2}g''(a)+O(h^3),\\g(a-h)&=g(a)-hg'(a)+\frac{h^2}{2}g''(a)+O(h^3).\end{align}$$
So that, one gets:
$$\frac{g(a+h)-2g(a)+g(a-h)}{h^2}=g''(a)+O(h).$$
Whence the result.

Comment: why will the taylor expansion exists?

Comment: By assumption $g$ is $C^2$, the starting point being that for all $C^1$ function, one has:
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+\int_x^{x+h}f'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Use the fact that
$$g(a+h)=g(a)+g'(a)h+\frac{g''(a)}{2}h^2+o(h^2),$$
and
$$g(a-h)=g(a)-g'(a)h+\frac{g''(a)}{2}h^2+o(h^2).$$

Comment: why will the taylor expansion exists?

Comment: @user8795: because $g$ is $\mathcal C^2$.